# IBM DB2 custom function syntax

Tags: java, function, db2

I have a custom regex DB2 function as follows: -

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION REGEXP_LIKE(SOURCE VARCHAR(3000), REGEX VARCHAR(512), 
MODE VARCHAR(3))

RETURNS INTEGER
FENCED 
NOT DETERMINISTIC
NO SQL
LANGUAGE JAVA
PARAMETER STYLE JAVA
EXTERNAL NAME 'db2_regex:com.ibm.avalanche.udf.regex.Regexp.regexpLike'
NO EXTERNAL ACTION
@
```

This is taken from the following article (http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-1011db2luwpatternmatch/index.html?ca=drs-)

This function can be used as follows: -

```
select ID from TABLE where 
REGEXP_LIKE(STRING, 'regex', 'i') > 0
```

The oracle version is as follows: -

```
select ID from TABLE where 
REGEXP_LIKE(STRING, 'regex', 'i')
```

Note that it doesn't require the greater than zero ( > 0 ).

My question is: - Can I achieve this Oracle syntax in the previous DB2 function.  I think the key mybe is the "RETURNS INTEGER"?

I've tried a few different things, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried? Try posting your solution and we can see where we can help.

Comment: I just tried changing the return type.  I'm not sure if this can be achieved in the WHERE statement on the sql as there must always be a return type.  If the return type was a boolean then you might not need the 

> 0  

bit.

Answer (score 0):

DB2 9.7 for Linux, UNIX, and Windows only supports the boolean data type inside of PL/SQL code modules that are running in a DB2 database created with the Oracle compatibility vectors enabled.

Consequently, you won't be able to define a UDF that returns a boolean type, nor will you be able to specify SQL predicates that check against boolean values (aside from built-in boolean expressions such as EXISTS, IS NULL, etc).